# "cordova platform add" fails to restore plugin randomly

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

cordova 8.0.0
node 8.11.1
npm 5.6.0

In our build process we call "cordova platform add android" which installs all plugins and the required platform before we build the project.

After i upgraded cordova to version 8.0.0 and all the plugins (and their dependencies) i always get an error when calling the platform add.

The error i get is:

> Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" from config.xml. You
>   might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3 via registry. Probably this is either a
>   connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect. Check your connection
>   and plugin name/version/URL. Failed to get absolute path to installed
>   module

It appears that changing the order of the plugins causes the same error to a different plugin!
node_modules is updated with the correct plugins.
installing the plugin manually via "cordova plugin add" pass successfully.

Any idea what can cause this weird behavior?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "lol",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "2.4.1",
    "com.plugin.imei": "https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-imei.git",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.1",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
    "cordova-custom-config": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-ble-central": "1.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-common": "1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-iossocketscommon": "1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp": "1.3.7",
    "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-network": "1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-imei": "https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-imei.git",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-keyboard": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-photo-library": "2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.4.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "4.0.8",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.1",
    "sqli-cordova-disk-space-plugin": "1.0.2",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "1.7.2"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-custom-config": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ble-central": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-common": {},
      "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-iossocketscommon": {},
      "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp": {},
      "cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-network": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
      "cordova-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
      "sqli-cordova-disk-space-plugin": {},
      "com.plugin.imei": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-photo-library": {},
      "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serv": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget defaultlocale="en-US" id="lol" version="13.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
  <name>lol</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">Apache Cordova Team</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <vs:features />
  <custom-preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <custom-preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
  <custom-preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
  <custom-preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <custom-preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="900000" />
  <custom-preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <custom-preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
  <custom-preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
  <custom-preference name="WindowsToastCapable" value="true" />
  <custom-preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <custom-preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
  <custom-preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#121212" />
  <custom-preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
  <custom-preference name="ShowTitle" value="False" />
  <custom-preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
  <custom-preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
  <custom-preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <custom-preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
  <custom-preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="30" src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="310" src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="44" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="106" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="70" src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="170" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon height="99" src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
    <icon height="159" src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xxhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xxxhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xxhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xxxhdpi-landscape.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@3x~iphone~comany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~ipad~comany.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash height="300" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
    <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash height="1280" src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.png" width="768" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <custom-preference name="android-manifest/@xmlns:tools" value="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
    <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@tools:replace" value="android:allowBackup" />
    <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:allowBackup" value="false" />
    <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:fullBackupContent" value="false" />
    <custom-config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.3.1" tools:replace="android:value" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    </custom-config-file>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <custom-preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-SWIFT_VERSION" value="3.0" xcconfigEnforce="true" />
    <custom-config-file parent="UIBackgroundModes" target="*-Info.plist">
      <array>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
      </array>
    </custom-config-file>
  </platform>
  <engine name="android" spec="7.1.1" />
  <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.4" />
  <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" spec="5.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="5.0.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="4.0.0">
    <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Need microphone access to function properly" />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ble-central" spec="1.2.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="4.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.0.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="0.1.9" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-common" spec="1.0.7" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-iossocketscommon" spec="1.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp" spec="1.3.7" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-network" spec="1.1.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="2.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-keyboard" spec="1.2.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="2.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="2.4.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="4.0.8" />
  <plugin name="sqli-cordova-disk-space-plugin" spec="1.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
  <plugin name="com.plugin.imei" spec="https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-imei.git" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="1.2.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.0.3">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Need camera access to function properly" />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Need photo library access to function properly" />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.1.16" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="3.0.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-photo-library" spec="2.1.1">
    <variable name="PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Need photo library access to function properly" />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" spec="1.7.2" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Try to remove and add again /platform(s)?/.